# Oracle RAW(16) vs 2 BIGINT number

Tags: oracle11g

My java program generates a random UUID number which consist of 2 long number. I can store this as 2 BIGINT number in 2 column in Oracle or store as a RAW(16) byte array in a single column. Which one is more efficient for storage in Oracle?

Thanks,

Comment: You should use whichever is most appropriate for the application, data and processing. Storage size shouldn't really be a significant concern any more, as long as whatever you use is appropriate.

Comment: The table that i am about to modify is very big, it is in the range of 50TB. So size is one aspect but what i worry is the impact on performance on this table from the RAW column.